# ng-repeat causing infinite loop in controller. Setting breakpoint show controller code executed infinitely

Tags: angularjs, html, drywall

I am using Angular-Drywall and ngCart. Not very expert with this Angular and JS thing :D.

This is my html from template (main.tpl.html)

```
<div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="item in products">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img ng-src="{{ item.imageUrl }}">
                <h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>
                <p>{{ item.snippet }}</p>
                <h3 class="price">{{ item.name.length*10-.01 | currency}}</h3>
                <ngcart-addtocart id="{{ item.id }}"
                           name="{{ item.name }}"
                           price="{{ item.name.length*10-.01  }}"
                           data="item"
                           quantity="1"
                           quantity-max="30">
                    Add To Cart
                </ngcart-addtocart></div>
</div>
```

And this is my controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('AppCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', 'i18nNotifications', 'localizedMessages', 'ngCart',
    function ($http, $scope, i18nNotifications, localizedMessages, ngCart) {

        ngCart.setShipping(15.00);
        ngCart.setTaxRate(13);

        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data/phones.json'})
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.products = data;
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("LOOP!");
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                    console.log("ERROR!");
                });

        $scope.notifications = i18nNotifications;

        $scope.removeNotification = function (notification) {
            i18nNotifications.remove(notification);
        };

        $scope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
            i18nNotifications.pushForCurrentRoute('errors.route.changeError', 'error', {}, {rejection: rejection});
        });
    }]);
```

I have confirmed ng-repeat is the root cause because removing that code means everything is peachy and no infinite loop.

I have also verify that products is a valid array.

What happen is that, with the html code, the controller keep reloading and executing, consuming resources until Chrome finally ask me to kill it.

Appreciate help. Have been troubleshooting this without much progress few hours now!

EDIT:

The different between working ngCart sample is (using stateProvider and ui.router library)

```
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

while my non working code use this (using routeProvider)

```
<div class="page">
    <div ng-view class="container"></div>
</div>
```

Code from index.html, showing where the template is inserted. Working one is using ui-view while the non working one is using ng-view.

If this is the reason, appreciate it if someone can explain why.

Comment: What's the intention behind this: `{{ item.name.length*10-.01 | currency}}` ?

Comment: I can't see why your ng-repeat won't work, my gut feeling is that it has something to do with ngcart-addtocart (that I don't know).
Did you try (just for testing) to remove ngcart-addtocart and see if ng-repeat works (this way you know where the problem comes from).

Comment: @MatthewCawley the code is from ngCart sample. And thanks for pointing that out. I just realize that the sample use product name length to calculate price and the -0.01 is there just to make the price look believeable.

Comment: @Tonio you are spot on! Removed that html you asked and the infinite loop stopped. This actually gel well with what I read while researching this problem. In short, something is missing that cause the / to be loaded again, which then will cause index.html to be called and the infinite loop. I am troubleshooting this further by doing comparison between my code that is not working and ngcart sample code that is working.

Comment: Updated my question to include different between working and non working index.html where the template is inserted. The other thing about missing ngCart java script file. I check this and confirm that ngCart.js is included in index.html and it is available to the browser since I can open it from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem I had in the past that seems related to your issue:
If you include whatever directive that access a template through "templateUrl" but for some reasons, angular can't resolve the templateUrl of this directive, by default it will return the template for index.html which will contain again your directive and because the templateUrl for the directive is not found, it default again to index.html

and so on....

This is most likely your issue here

Comment: I am going to accept this as the answer now. But I have not yet identify the root cause and solve this. Will troubleshoot this later and come back!